# Fay: unable to resolve qualified names ffi?

Tags: haskell, fay

I have installed:

- fay-0.19.0.1
- fay-base-0.19

And I'm trying to compile

```
-- test.hs
module Main where

import FFI

main = ffi "alert('hello world');"
```

with

```
fay test.hs
```

And getting

```
fay: unable to resolve qualified names ffi
```

Note that I am able to compile things with fay-jquery, fay-text, etc.  Full source files that compile and run (with fay-base) and do what I expect them to do when executing them.  But as soon as I try to use `ffi` in any of then, I get this error.

fay-jquery, fay-dom, and other packages that use ffi seem to behave well when I import them.

I'm not sure what else to mention?  I'm on ghc 7.6.3, running Ubuntu.

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import Prelude and add a type signature to anything using FFI.

```
module Console (main) where

import Prelude
import FFI

main :: Fay ()
main = putStrLn (showInt (fib 10))

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

showInt :: Int -> String
showInt = ffi "%1+''"
```

Compiles.

Commenting out `import Prelude` returns error: `src/console.hs:7:8: Not in scope: putStrLn'` among others.

Commenting out `showInt :: Int -> String` returns error: `fay: your FFI declaration needs a type signature: showInt = ffi "%1+''"`

Fix those issues and give it another whirl.

I am told by our glorious leaders of the Fay Soviet that `import Prelude` is no longer necessary if you have the right stamps on your labor passport.

Comment: As of fay 0.19 you don't need to import Prelude explicitly.

Comment: Ah, it looks like my problem was just not having a type signature on ffi.  I'll test it on my real code and confirm.